# JXplore on Ubuntu 18.04 crashed

Tags: 18.04, java

I see after some updates on Ubuntu 18.04 desktop and server that JXplorer doesn't want to open. I'm trying to figure out what happened as this application is necessary to my work.

Code from terminal:

```
wrz 12, 2018 12:42:20 PM com.ca.directory.jxplorer.JXplorer printTime
INFO: main start
TIME: Wed Sep 12 12:42:20 CEST 2018  (407)

wrz 12, 2018 12:42:20 PM com.ca.directory.jxplorer.JXplorer checkJavaEnvironment
INFO: running java from: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
wrz 12, 2018 12:42:20 PM com.ca.directory.jxplorer.JXplorer checkJavaEnvironment
INFO: running java version 10.0.2
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.AWTError: Assistive Technology not found: org.GNOME.Accessibility.AtkWrapper
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.newAWTError(Toolkit.java:472)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.fallbackToLoadClassForAT(Toolkit.java:488)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap$KeySpliterator.forEachRemaining(HashMap.java:1608)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.loadAssistiveTechnologies(Toolkit.java:532)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(Toolkit.java:613)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.getToolkit(Window.java:1375)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.init(Window.java:518)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:549)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:423)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:388)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.SwingUtilities$SharedOwnerFrame.<init>(SwingUtilities.java:1919)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.SwingUtilities.getSharedOwnerFrame(SwingUtilities.java:1995)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JWindow.<init>(JWindow.java:183)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JWindow.<init>(JWindow.java:135)
    at com.ca.directory.jxplorer.JXplorer.JXplorerFullInit(JXplorer.java:84)
    at com.ca.directory.jxplorer.JXplorer.<init>(JXplorer.java:76)
    at com.ca.directory.jxplorer.JXplorer.main(JXplorer.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.GNOME.Accessibility.AtkWrapper
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:374)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.fallbackToLoadClassForAT(Toolkit.java:485)
```

What could be the problem and how can I fix it?